# Assigning Parent Number to Child Number in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, parent-child, teradatasql

I've been trying to assign parent case number to child case number using Teradata SQL. I have the table

**Patient Table**

| PatientID | Cal_Date | FirstVisitCreateTs | Location | VisitNum | VisitFlag | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-09-22 | 2021-09-22 10:30:23 | Ground | 101112 | 0 | First Visit ID opened |
| 1234 | 2021-09-23 | 2021-09-22 10:30:23 | Ground | 101112 | 0 | First Visit ID opened |
| 1234 | 2021-09-24 | 2021-09-24 11:42:41 | Ground | 111213 | 0 | Second Visit ID opened before First getting closed |
| 1234 | 2021-09-25 | 2021-09-24 11:42:41 | Ground | 111213 | 1 | Second Visit ID closed |
| 1234 | 2021-09-25 | 2021-09-22 10:30:23 | Ground | 101112 | 1 | First Visit ID closed |
| 1234 | 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-02 02:15:34 | Ground | 121314 | 0 | Third Visit ID opened |
| 1234 | 2021-10-03 | 2021-10-02 02:15:34 | Ground | 121314 | 1 | Third Visit ID closed |

And my desired output should be like
**Output Table**

| PatientID | Cal_Date | FirstVisitCreateTs | Location | VisitNum | VisitFlag | *ParentVisitNum* | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-09-22 | 2021-09-22 10:30:23 | Ground | 101112 | 0 | NULL | First Visit ID opened |
| 1234 | 2021-09-23 | 2021-09-22 10:30:23 | Ground | 101112 | 0 | NULL | First Visit ID opened |
| 1234 | 2021-09-24 | 2021-09-24 11:42:41 | Ground | 111213 | 0 | NULL | Second Visit ID opened before First getting closed |
| 1234 | 2021-09-25 | 2021-09-24 11:42:41 | Ground | 111213 | 1 | 101112 | Second Visit ID closed |
| 1234 | 2021-09-25 | 2021-09-22 10:30:23 | Ground | 101112 | 1 | 101112 | First Visit ID closed |
| 1234 | 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-02 02:15:34 | Ground | 121314 | 0 | NULL | Third Visit ID opened |
| 1234 | 2021-10-03 | 2021-10-02 02:15:34 | Ground | 121314 | 1 | 121314 | Third Visit ID closed |

**Key points:**

1. *ParentVisitNum* is assigned to child when first VisitNum flag is not closed (0-Open,1-Closed).
2. Child is defined as any New VisitNum that is opened before the First VisitNum getting closed.

**In this example:** For the PatientID (1234), the first VisitNum is 101112 which is opened on 2021-09-22 and another VisitNum (111213) is opened on 2021-09-24 for the same PatientID (1234) before getting the first(parent) VisitNum closed (VisitFlag=1). In this case we will have to assign ParentVisitNum as 101112 to 111213 when it is closed(VisitNum=1).

I've tried many different TD SQL queries but found no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first two lines open the same visit, is this correct? And the 1st visit closed before the 2nd? Would probably be easier if open/close row pairs get combined into one row.

Comment: Hello @dnoeth, second visit(121314) has been closed before the first visit (101112). Hence, the parent for second visit(121314) is first visit (101112). Second visit necessarily need not close but if any new visit gets opened before the previous visit getting closed then that new visit becomes the child.

Comment: Ok, and the two lines opening the 1st visit? And if visit #3 opens before #1 and #2 close?

Comment: @dnoeth If the visit #3 opens before  #1 and #2 close then the parent for  visit #3 will be  visit #1. This is because the first parent visit is still open and another visit# has opened up.

Comment: Again: The first two lines open the same visit #1, is this correct? Is it possible to have more than two rows (open/close) for the same visitnum?

Comment: Yes correct, first two rows signify the Visit#1 is open but there will be only one close Flag after which the visit# is closed.